# python pandas yahoo stock data error

Tags: python, pandas, urllib2

i am try to pullout intraday aapl stock data by yahoo. but there problem i facing with my program..

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime
import urllib2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
get = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/aapl/chartdata;type=quote;range=1d/csv'
getdata = urllib2.urlopen(get).read()
df = pd.read_csv(getdata, skiprows=17, header=None)
print df.head()
```

and error is this....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "getyahoodata.py", line 10, in <module>
df = pd.read_csv(getdata, skiprows=16, header=None)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 420, in parser_f
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 218, in _read
parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 502, in __init__
self._make_engine(self.engine)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 610, in _make_engine
self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 972, in __init__
self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
File "parser.pyx", line 330, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:3200)
File "parser.pyx", line 557, in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source  (pandas/parser.c:5559)
IOError: File uri:/instrument/1.0/aapl/chartdata;type=quote;range=1d/csv
```

ticker:aapl

```
1413811857,98.3800,98.4999,98.3000,98.3800,1327900
1413811908,98.5200,98.6196,98.3360,98.3800,380100
1413811978,98.4200,98.5300,98.3850,98.4700,993800

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
more and more


1413835019,99.8800,99.9100,99.8600,99.9000,524300
1413835079,99.8600,99.8850,99.8500,99.8700,600400
1413835139,99.8100,99.8600,99.7900,99.8500,530900
1413835199,99.7201,99.8301,99.7000,99.8200,1001500
1413835200,99.7600,99.7600,99.7600,99.7600,1720500
```

does not exist

in yahoo data pulling program show full data...but when i am useing google it work perfect...please try above program help to write program...thanks...

Comment: Please give an example of the output you're getting, and the output you are expecting. Please also give the Google URL you are using. Your question is not very clear as-is.

Answer (score 3):

`pd.read_csv` accepts a path or a filelike object.  You're passing the text itself, and it's trying to read that as a filename.  You can just pass the URL (although `get` isn't a great variable name..)

```
In [102]: df = pd.read_csv(get, skiprows=17, header=None)

In [103]: df.head()
Out[103]: 
            0        1        2        3        4        5
0  1413811859  98.3800  98.5000  98.3100  98.4800  1348400
1  1413811860  98.4775  98.6196  98.3265  98.3701   452200
2  1413811977  98.4250  98.5400  98.3800  98.4700   900000
3  1413812039  98.4800  98.4900  98.3900  98.4250   378100
4  1413812040  98.8300  98.8500  98.4700  98.4800   495300
```